# not sure why toggling to show content isn't pushing down next piece of content

Tags: css

Not a full-time front-end developer but need to finish this.

I am pulling some images from an ajax request and pushing them into a div and hiding it.  Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

When I toggle the class to display it, the images show (wave pictures in screenshot) and DOES push down the other content.

However, there is a border-top on the next piece of content and this seems to stay in place (the blue border in screenshot).

If I highlight the image content in Firebug, it really doesn't show up. How would I make it so that the border of the next element gets pushed down correctly?

thx

**edit 1**
removed float:left for @Ramon - seems to remove issue but now things are not running inline. Is there another way to set them up rather than float:left. Would a horizontal list break onto multiple lines?

[image]

Comment: you should post the output (relevant HTML/CSS)

Answer (score 0):

You must check many things, among them:

1. Check that the blue border element is not positioned absolutely.
2. This is just a trick, just put a: `<div style="clear:both"></div>` between both.

   3 Check if there are any unclosed html element like the div we can see in the code pasted above.

4 Check if any element involved is floating or has the top css attribute set.

For more help, please give a little bit more information. Hope that helps,

Comment: so the images ios-image-box is float:left so that they line-up and break within the wrapper that they exist in. If I take the float:left out, they become a vertical list. The ios-image-box is a display:table with the inside link as a display:table-cell to make it vertically align correctly

Comment: Well, what I recommend to you is to still use the float left, but, at the end, between the element of blue border, and the elements that are showing in the list, just put a <div class="clearfix"></div> as I see you have this useful css class already declared.